# How to show category name once if its already rendered within a map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically, I have a bunch of categories that pharmaceutical drugs are classed in. I also have individual drugs that have a class.

Right now, my code basically maps all categories from the category array and if the class of the drug matches the category, it places it underneath it.

However, I only want to render a category in the drop-down if drug.class matches it.

tldr:
drug.class doesn't match a category? then don't show the category in the dropdown.
drug.class matches a category? render the category and place the drug underneath that category, however, do NOT repeat the category for every drug.

Basically this rendering ONLY if drug.class matches the category.name, so I don't have empty categories with no drugs underneath.

```
        <ListSubheader key={category.id}>{category.name}</ListSubheader>
```

I hope I've explained this to the best of my ability, here's my code:

```
 {categories.map(category => 
   (<span>
        <ListSubheader key={category.id}>{category.name}</ListSubheader>
        {drugs.map(drug => drug.class.toLowerCase()===category.name.toLowerCase() ? 
        <>
        { patient.age <= 12 && drug.suggestedDosePediatric != "Restricted" &&
        <MenuItem key={drug._id} onClick={()=>handleClick(drug)} value={drug.value}>{drug.name}</MenuItem>
        }
         { patient.age > 12 &&
        <MenuItem key={drug._id} onClick={()=>handleClick(drug)} value={drug.value}>{drug.name}</MenuItem>
        }
        </>
         : null)}
   </span>)
)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the drugs by class.

```
// assuming the following helper
function groupBy(iterable, keyFn) {
  const groups = new Map();
  for (const item of iterable) {
    const key = keyFn(item);
    if (!groups.has(key)) groups.set(key, []);
    groups.get(key).push(item);
  }
  return groups;
}
```

With the above helper (or something similar from a library) we can group the drugs and then iterate over them.

```
if (patient.age <= 12) {
  drugs = drugs.filter(drug => drug.suggestedDosePediatric != "Restricted");
}

const drugsByCategoryName = groupBy(drugs, drug => drug.class.toLowerCase());

// ...

{Array.from(drugsByCategoryName, ([categoryName, drugs]) => (
  <span>
    <ListSubheader>{categoryName}</ListSubheader>
    {drugs.map((drug) => (
      <MenuItem key={drug._id} onClick={()=>handleClick(drug)} value={drug.value}>
        {drug.name}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </span>
))}
```

The above essentially answers your question. Although you might have noticed that the category is currently only a name (`key={category.id}` is missing). To get access to all properties of a category it's a good idea to create a lookup object for categories first, since you'll have to find the category belonging to each drug.

```
const categoriesByName = new Map(categories.map((category) => (
  [category.name.toLowerCase(), category]
)));
```

Then instead of grouping by category name, group the drug by the category object.

```
const drugsByCategory = groupBy(drugs, (drug) => (
  categoriesByName.get(drug.class.toLowerCase()))
));
```

This new definition of `drugsByCategory` is grouped by `category` object, not just the name. Which allows you access to the category properties when iterating over it.

```
{Array.from(drugsByCategoryName, ([category, drugs]) => (
  <span>
    <ListSubheader key={category.id}>{category.name}</ListSubheader>
    {/* ... */}
  </span>
))}
```

---

There is still a small "loophole" within the above code that could result in an exception. What if the list of `drugs` includes a `drug.class` that is not present within the `categories`? Such a scenario might not exist, in which case you don't have to worry about it. If this scenario does exist the above code already handles it pretty well. `categoriesByName.get(drug.class.toLowerCase()))` will return `undefined`, meaning that all drugs with a non-existent `drug.class` are listed under the `undefined` key within the `drugsByCategory` Map.

This allow for different solutions. You could ignore all drugs with a non-existent `drug.class` by removing the group from the collection.

```
drugsByCategory.delete(undefined);
```

Another option would be to add an "others" category at the end.

```
const others = drugsByCategory.get(undefined);
drugsByCategory.delete(undefined);

// ...

{Array.from(drugsByCategory, (category, drugs) => (
   <span>
     <ListSubheader key={category.id}>{category.name}</ListSubheader>
     {/* ... */}
   </span>
))}
{others && (
   <span>
     <ListSubheader key="others">Others</ListSubheader>
     {/* ... */}
   </span>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

`drugs.filter(drug => drug.class.toLowerCase() === category.name.toLowerCase()`will give you the array with only the drugs you want. You can then map it. They can be chained together, like this:

```
 {categories.map(category => 
   (<span>
        <ListSubheader key={category.id}>{category.name}</ListSubheader>
        {drugs.filter(drug => drug.class.toLowerCase() === category.name.toLowerCase()).map(drug => drug.class.toLowerCase()===category.name.toLowerCase() ? 
        <>
        { patient.age <= 12 && drug.suggestedDosePediatric != "Restricted" &&
        <MenuItem key={drug._id} onClick={()=>handleClick(drug)} value={drug.value}>{drug.name}</MenuItem>
        }
         { patient.age > 12 &&
        <MenuItem key={drug._id} onClick={()=>handleClick(drug)} value={drug.value}>{drug.name}</MenuItem>
        }
        </>
         : null)}
   </span>)
)}
```

Comment: <ListSubheader key={category.id}>{category.name}</ListSubheader>

I only want this to render if there are drugs that actually MATCH this category tho.

Comment: The code above does just that, in the filter method it skips all drugs that does not have the same class as `category.name`

Comment: I've updated the main question, the code does the same thing as before unfortunately.